# How Add columns in Excel file to add manual datas to complete sql query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I use an sql query to export datas in excel file.
it return severals columns of quantiy of stock. I want add some columns in the excel sheet to add previsions (manual statement) and some columns to do some formula between my new column and columns from sql query.
My problems is when I update my query in Excel... my columns added manually don't follow the inserted rows. I use Excel 2016. I try to take sample on [Power Query](https://exceleratorbi.com.au/self-referencing-tables-power-query/). But I don't find how do it
Thanks For your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, merging severals solutions I find a way
First build a request on your SQL Sever
2nd Make a second sheet with key column and additionnal column
3rd make a function on change event sheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
testlok
End Sub
Sub testlok()
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Dim c As Range
 Dim firstAddress As String
 Dim find As Boolean
 Dim Cell As Range
 For Each Cell In Feuil1.Range("A2:A" & Feuil1.Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row)
find = False
With Feuil2.Range("A2:A" & Feuil2.Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row)
    Set c = .find(Cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues,lookat:=xlwhole)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        find = (Feuil2.Range(c.Address).Offset(0, 1).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value)
        If Not find Then
            Do
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
                If firstAddress = c.Address Then Exit Do
                If Not c Is Nothing Then
                    find = (Feuil2.Range(c.Address).Offset(0, 1).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value)
                End If
            Loop While (Not c Is Nothing And Not find)
        End If
    End If
End With
If Not find Then
     if Feuil2.Range("A" & Cell.Row).Value <>"" then Feuil2.Rows(Cell.Row).EntireRow.Insert
     Feuil2.Range("A" & Cell.Row).Value = Cell.Value'1rst part of key
     Feuil2.Range("B" & Cell.Row).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value'2nd part of key
     Feuil2.Range("C" & Cell.Row).Value = 0 'Default value
End If
Next Cell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

In my sample I've 2 columns for the key.
An third, Make a new query from a table and merge your sql query and the table of 2nd page

How use it?
1/Update sql query
3/Update manually additionnal column
4/Update merging request

If someone have a better solution, don't hesitate to share it.